# Safely using incrementing number as key in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have a path within firebase realtime database where I want to use incrementing keys for:

`/foo/1 {a: "some data"}`

`/foo/2 {a: "some other data"}`

Right now, I'm querying the last /foo/ record to get the last number, and setting /foo/3 as the latest object. However this is a race condition-- if two users try to do this at the same time, it could lead to them both creating /foo/3 (and one overwriting the other).

Is there any way I can do this safely? It looks like realtime database has some limitied support for transactions, but I'm not sure if they can be used for this use case.

Thanks in advance!

edit: Here is exactly what I'm doing currently

```js
const fooCollection = await admin.database().ref("foo").limitToLast(1).get();

let lastFooId;

fooCollection.forEach(snapshot => {
  lastFooId = snapshot.key
})

let newFooId = 0;

if(lastFooId) {
  newFooId = parseInt(lastFooId) + 1;
}

await admin.database().ref(`/foo/${newOrderId}`).set(fooData);
```

Is there a way I can make this a transaction on the /foo/ path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to perform a query inside a transaction in the Firebase Realtime Database.

The idiomatic way to do this is to keep a counter value at a known path (typically referred to as a sequence in other databases), instead of using a query to determine its value - and then use a transaction (or multi-path update) to write both the new value to that sequence/value and the new node.

This would also solve the inherent scalability problem that comes from querying an even-growing list. Even when that limit is at the hundreds of thousand (or nowadays more likely: millions) of nodes, it is still better to use an approach that doesn't have such a scalability limit.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you! So update the sequence in a transaction, and use that as the new key? I updated my code sample in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/NathanC/c85d61f98e19b29a337a7ce5592fcf0e

Does that generally look like the idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: Also, I couldn't find too much documentation on realtime database transactions. Do you know if it auto-retries committing the transaction if there is a conflict, or do I need to do that manually?

Comment: You're using two transactions there, so that's not a single atomic transaction. You can either perform a single transaction over both locations, or use a single multi-path write operation on both locations - using security rules to reject the case where some client performs a write where the counter doesn't increment by 1.

Comment: Realtime database transactions only allow a get-and-update for a single path, right? Firestore transactions are more powerful, but I'm not using that.

I think what I have works? If two clients run the code at the same time, the counters will increment atomically for each client to different fooIds. The clients will never be given the same id as each other.

Comment: Correct, the IDs will be unique. But a malicious client could write the ID that another client generated, which *may* be unwanted. In such scenarios having a single write operation would be the only solution.

Comment: This is being done in a cloud function, so the client is just exposed a "create new Foo" function which auto increments and adds.

Comment: But the security rules to enforce a multiple write action that increments the counter is a cool pattern, and I'll definitely keep it in mind for the future. Thanks again!